# How to define a schema in Eve for a resource that contains a list of dicts?

Tags: python, eve

I need a resource to store a `list` of `dicts`. I couldn't find any info on this in the docs. (I hope I'm not overlooking something..)

E.g this is an example of what the resource I have in mind would give me, when I run a `HTTP GET` on it (see `toys` for the list of dicts):

```
  {
  "_items": [
    {
        'group_id': 0,
        'toys': [
            {'name': 'foo', 'color': 'red'},
            {'name': 'bar', 'color': 'green'},
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        'group_id': 1,
        'toys': [
            {'name': 'foo', 'color': 'orange'},
            {'name': 'bar', 'color': 'pruple'},
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
```

How can I write a schema to define a list of dicts in Eve?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. A schema for a `list` of `dicts` in Eve looks like this:

```
my_ressource = {
  'schema': {
    'list_of_dicts': {
      'type': 'list',
      'schema': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'schema': {
          'name': {'type': 'string'},
          'age': {'type': 'integer'},
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

DOMAIN = {
    'my_ressource': my_ressource,
}
```